# Laravel 4 : Passing data from database to view

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I wish to make a select box containing some categories of items. This select box should have the data from database.
so first i created my blade

admin.blade.php :

```
    <h2>Add Category</h2>
    {{ HTML::ul($errors->all(), array('class'=>'errors')) }}
    {{ Form::open(array( 'url'=>'admin/category/add', $title="Admin Control Panel")) }}

    <p>
    {{ Form::label('Category Name:') }}
    {{ Form::text('category_name', Input::old('category_name'))  }}
   </p>

    <p>
    {{ Form::select('parent_category',  array('' => 'Select Category', '0 ' => 'Main Category',))  }}
    {{ Form::label('Parent Category:') }}   
   </p>


    <p>
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('name' => 'save')) }}
    </p>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

and then i created my controller:

```
    class CategoryController extends BaseController  
    {
    public function add()
    {
    $category_list = CategoryModel::select();
    return View::make('admin')->with('category_list', $category_list);
    }
```

i need to display this array in my select box. but i don't know how to do that. please suggest a proper way!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
return View::make('admin')->with('category_list', $category_list);
```

What this is saying is create a response and return it to the client.  The response is going to be generated using the blade template `admin`, and we're going to pass the contents of the variable `$category_list` to the view which will be able to reference it internally as `$category_list` (the first string parameter to the `with` function).

Therefore, inside your view if you want to access your category list you can do this:

```
{{ $category_list->title }}
```

Assuming, of course, that `$category_list` here is a single model with an attribute `title`.  If `$category_list` is a collection of models (or an array), you can just use `foreach`:

```
@foreach($category_list as $category) 
    {{ $category->title }}
@endforeach
```

If what you're doing is trying to build a select list based off of the entries in your database for a given model, you can simply do this:

```
{{ Form::select('category', CategoryModel::list('title', 'id')) }}
```

Of course, you can generate that array in your controller and pass it down as you are doing now, too.

Comment: Thank you for answering . but i have a doubt.In this step :: {{ Form::select('category', CategoryModel::list('title', 'id')) }} what is 'list'?

Comment: The `list` method on models is specifically for generating an array to use in a drop-down select box.  The first argument is the property on the model to use as the display in the drop down, the second argument is the property to use as the value of each drop down element.

Comment: sir, i got the result i just changed the select portion {{ Form::select('parent_category', array('' => 'Select Category', '0 ' => 'Main Category') + $category_list) }} . it works. and thank you very much for spending time for me.